# How to efficiently access/change one item in each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A with size (nr,nc), a vector of column indices B (so B has size (nr,1) and every element in B is an integer between 1 and nc), and I want to do something to every element in A that is of the form A(i,B(i)) for i between 1 and nr, efficiency being the key concern.
For concreteness, say C is a vector of size (nr,1), the goal is to do

```
for i=1:nr 
A(i,B(i))=A(i,B(i))+C(i)
end
```

more efficiently. The context is usually that nr>>nc (because when nr is large vectorization is efficient for many operations). I have gotten a factor 3 speedup by using an indicator function approach:

```
for k=1:nc
A(:,k)=A(:,k)+(k==B).*C
end
```

Are there other ways (more efficient hopefully) to do this?
I guess this is similar to many questions on double-indexing, but it's concretely one I run into all the time.

Comment: Thank you, nimrodm and groovingandi! So the trick is to bring it down to linear indexing, where vectorization applies. In profiler timing, your solutions are equivalent to the "indicator function" one when (nr,nc)=(10^5,2), but a good 4 times faster when (nr,nc)=(10^5,20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linear indexing:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), 1:nr, B');
A(idx) = A(idx) + C';
```

or (edited version with one less transpose)

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), (1:nr)', B);
A(idx) = A(idx) + C;
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm just not sure about the transpose on C in the last line, as size(idx) is (nr,1) then the size of A(idx) is also (nr,1) so just adding it to C should be OK?

Comment: @imateapot size(idx) should be (1, nr) as 1:nr and B' are also size (1, nr). Alternatively, you could also use `sub2ind(size(A), (1:nr)', B)` and the C without transpose

Comment: You could even potentially speed this up further by cutting out the SUB2IND overhead and computing the linear indices directly: `idx = (1:nr).'+nr.*(B-1);`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use linear indexing of the matrix. You will need a vector `v` holding the offsets of the first element in each line, then index using `A(v + B)`. For example:

```
>A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

>B = [1 2 3] % we want the 1st element of row 1, 2nd of row 2, 3rd of row 3

>ii = [0 3 6] + B

>a(ii)

1     5     9
```

**Note**: As *groovingandi* had shown, it is also possible (and more readable) to use `sub2ind` to generate the `ii` linear indices vector. The idea is essentially the same.